# Why is R telling me "invalid subscript type 'list' " when I try to extract variables from an nls() result?

Tags: r, lapply

`transgression2` is a `list` with all of the nls results from 50000 nls runs stored in it. I'm trying to extract the coefficients from it.

Doing `transgression2[[1]]$m$getAllPars()` returns a named number list.

```
nlsCoefficients <- lapply(transgression2, function(x) (transgression2[[x]]$m$getAllPars()))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how `lapply` works.

We apply a function to each element in a list - it looks you are expecting the `x` to be the numeric index of each sublist, whereas `lapply` passes the sublist in itself.

Let's make a fake object that looks like yours - in this case we store 5 and 10 as the values, rather than a function:

```
transgression2 <- list(list('m' = list('getAllPars' = 5)), list('m' = list('getAllPars' = 10)))
```

We need to lapply on the transgression2, but the function is applied to each part inside it, like so:

```
lapply(transgression2, function(x) x$m$getAllPars)
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 10
```

You can see the difference here: We `lapply` for each index up to the length of transgression2, but use the same function you originally used:

```
lapply(1:length(transgression2), function(x) transgression2[[x]]$m$getAllPars)

[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 10
```

The original error is because you are trying to subset the list by it's sublist: R is interpreting your call as:

```
transgression2[[transgression2[[1]]]]
```

or

```
transgression2[[list('m' = list('getAllPars' = 5))]]
```

Like R says - you are trying to subscript with a list

Comment: When I change it to x, it gives me `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` instead

Comment: When I change it to x, it gives me `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` instead

Comment: In that case my guess about what your data looks like was wrong - try pasting the output of a smaller version of your data into the question: `str(transgression2)`